# How to cycle throught Java list

Tags: java

How would I make something cycle through a array and check if it equaled an item in a Java list? Example:

```
List<String> arraylist= new ArrayList<String>();
arrayList.add("ex3");
arrayList.add("ex2");
String arrayItems[] = {"ex1", "ex2", "ex3"};
int foundItem = 0;

for (int i = 0; i > arrayItems.length; i++) {
    if (boughtItems.equals(powerItems[i])) {
        foundItem++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your condition is the wrong way around it should be `i < arrayItems.length`

Comment: are there 4 different arrays in this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for each works fine for this:

```
for (String element : arraylist) {
  if (boughtItems.equals(element)) {
    foundItem++;
  }
}
```